# Count the number of contours

Tags: plotting

I have plotted a `ListContourPlot` and have not specified the number of contours that are plotted, just the range. Is there a way to count how many contours have been automatically plotted by Mathematica?

**EDIT**

If I have contours representing different values, is there a way to select the contour relative to a specific value?

Comment: I and J.M. interpreted the question differently. Are you trying to count the number of contours in his sense or in the sense that I counted them?

Comment: @C.E. Let us assume I have a contour plot with 10 contours and their value ranges from 1 to 10. How can I select the contour which represents the value of 7 (without selecting the 7th contour)?

Comment: What do you mean "select"?

Comment: @C.E. I mean extracting all the points belonging to the contour representing the value of 7.

Comment: You can use the same method that march uses in his answer. You apply `Normal` to the plot and then extract the lines using `Cases`. Select all lines such that if you take on of the coordinates in the line and apply your function then you get the number that you desire.

Comment: GEF, have you already considered to accept one of the given answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### FindDivisions

The list of automatically selected contours can be obtained using `FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}]` as the setting for `Contours`.

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
lcp1 = ListContourPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, ImageSize -> 300];
```

The default list of contours in `lcp1` can also be obtained using `FindDivisions` in the option setting for `Contours`. (See [this answer to a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161916/125).)

```
lcp2 = ListContourPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   Contours -> ((contoursFD = FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}]) &)];
```

The two graphics objects `lcp1` and `lcp2` are identical:

```
lcp1 == lcp2
```

> True

And the list `contoursFD` captured in `lcp2` is identical with the default list of contours in `lcp1`.

```
N @ contoursFD
```

> {0., 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}

These contours match the ones produced by @J.M.'s method using `Tooltip`s:

```
contoursTT = Reverse[Cases[lcp1, Tooltip[a_ /; Not[FreeQ[a, _Line]], t_] :> t, ∞]]
```

> {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1}

```
Row[{Show[lcp1, PlotLabel -> Style["contours : " <> ToString@contoursTT, 16]], 
  Show[lcp2, PlotLabel -> Style["contours : " <> ToString@N[contoursFD], 16]]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** `FindDivisions` also works to find the contour levels for the setting `Contours -> {Automatic, atmostn}` using  `atmostn` as the second argument of `FindDivisions`:

```
atmostn = 3;
lcp3a = ListContourPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Contours -> {Automatic, atmostn}];
contoursTT = Reverse[Cases[lcp3a, Tooltip[a_ /; Not[FreeQ[a, _Line]], t_] :> t, ∞]];
lcp3b = ListContourPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   Contours -> ((contoursFD = FindDivisions[{#, #2}, atmostn, Method -> {}]) &)];
contoursFD == contoursTT
```

> True

```
Style[Row[{Show[lcp3a, PlotLabel ->  
      Pane[Style["contours : " <> ToString@N[contoursTT], 12], 
       ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}]],
   Show[lcp3b, PlotLabel -> 
     Pane[Style["contours : " <> ToString@N[contoursFD], 12], 
      ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}]]}], 
 ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]

For `atmostn = 25` we get

```
contoursFD == contoursTT
```

> True

[image]

**Update 2:** For the question added in the update:

> *assume I have a contour plot with 10 contours and their value ranges from 1 to 10. How can I select the contour which represents the value of 7 (without selecting the 7th contour)?*

***a contour plot with 10 contours and their value ranges from 1 to 10*:**

```
lcp10 = ListContourPlot[3 + data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  Contours -> Range[10], ContourShading -> None, 
  ContourStyle -> (ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; 10]])]
```

[image]

***How can I select the contour which represents the value of 7?***

```
lcpC7 = ListContourPlot[3 + data, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  Contours -> {7}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

```
lines = Cases[Normal@lcpC7, _Line, Infinity];
lines // Short
```

> {Line[{{100., 3.55836}, {99.9841, 3.5646}, <<24>> ,{97.1146, 4.}}], <<29>>, <<1>>}

```
Show[lcp10, Epilog -> {Blue, Thick, lines}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you're dealing with multiple contours corresponding to multiple heights, a hacky way is to count the number of `Tooltip[]` objects being used internally. For instance,

```
conts = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π}, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image: contours]

Then,

```
Count[conts, Tooltip[l : {__} /; MemberQ[l, Line[__]], v_?NumericQ], ∞]
   7
```

Here, counting `Line[]` objects would result in a gross overestimate. This is confirmed when one uses the explicit setting `Contours -> 7` in `ContourPlot[]`.

Answer (score 5):

### Original interpretation of the question

```
cp = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 1/2, {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Count[cp, _Line, ∞]
```

> `9`

To understand how this works you need to be familiar with how graphics is represented in Mathematica. Examining `FullForm[cp]` is a good start in case you don't know this yet.

Here is my take on the extra question using the same kind of approach:

```
cp = ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, 
   Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[cp, {Directive[col_, __], lines__Line} :> {col, Length[{lines}]}, ∞]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I think you are better off plotting the levels one by one and then using the approach here above.

```
cps = ContourPlot[#, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}] & /@ {Abs[
     Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5, Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Count[#, _Line, ∞] & /@ cps
```

> `{4, 9}`

### Alternative interpretation of the question

J.M. interpreted the question a little differently than I. My version of his code would not count tooltip labels, but would count colors instead. The reason is that it's slightly easier.

```
cp = ContourPlot[
  Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π},
  ContourShading -> None,
  ContourStyle -> (ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[100])
  ];

Count[cp, _RGBColor, ∞]
```

> `7`

Note that I did not need to know the number of levels in order to insert the colors, I only had to make sure to generate more colors than I had levels.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @JM, [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot) by default includes a tooltip for each contour value. The first element of each tooltip includes the [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) objects making up the contour, using [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex) coordinates. So, if you want to have an association tying each contour value with the [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) objects making up that contour, you can do the following:

```
assoc = Association @ Cases[
    Normal @ ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π}],
    Tooltip[x_, y_] :> y -> Cases[x,_Line,Infinity],
    Infinity
];
```

The total number of contours is:

```
Length @ assoc
```

> 7

and the [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line) objects associated with the contour 1.5 is:

```
assoc[1.5] //Short[#,10]&
```

> {Line[{{0.,1.04642},{0.0360218,1.04582},{0.0790736,1.04292},{0.1122,1.03923},{0.137919,1.03552},{0.213951,1.02025},{0.224399,1.01775},{0.249554,1.0098},{0.315379,0.988578},{0.336599,0.980251},<<19>>,{0.980251,0.336599},{0.988578,0.315379},{1.0098,0.249554},{1.01775,0.224399},{1.02025,0.213951},{1.03552,0.137919},{1.03923,0.1122},{1.04292,0.0790736},{1.04582,0.0360218},{1.04642,0.}}],<<7>>,Line[{{<<19>>,<<18>>},<<163>>}]}

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [C.E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141946/29734) to address the extra question, let's do the following. Taking the function

```
f[x_, y_] = Cos[x] + Cos[y];
```

as an example consider the contour plot:

```
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y],
        {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
        Contours -> {0.1, 0.5, 1}, ContourShading -> False]
```

[image]

If we do

```
assoc = GroupBy[Cases[Normal@cp, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity], f @@ #[[1]] &];
```

then we get an `Association` object that associates the value of the contour (as computed by `f @@ #[[1]] &`) to the list of contours with that value. Unfortunately, because of numerical error in the contour values, there are more than just the three (0.1, 0.5, and 1):

```
Keys@assoc // FullForm
(* List[1.`, 1.0000000000000002`, 0.9999999999999996`, 1.0000438962964133`, 0.4993229505918183`, 0.4993229505918182`, 0.4993229505918185`, 0.4993229505918175`, 0.5006924094447289`, 0.09990244696130435`, 0.09990244696130413`, 0.09990244696130446`, 0.10067337224158247`] *)
```

Maybe that's okay, because maybe we want to know the values on the contours to machine precision, but probably not. To get around this, we can use `Round` in our selector function, like so:

```
assoc = GroupBy[Cases[Normal@cp, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity], Round[f @@ #[[1]], 0.01] &];
```

The choice of `0.01` is made after examining what we get. Then:

```
Keys@assoc
(* {1., 0.5, 0.1} *)
```

To get the contours for a particular value, do, for instance,

```
assoc[1.]
```

To see how it works:

```
ListLinePlot@assoc[1.]
```

[image]