# How to get contour levels of picked automatically by ContourPlot?

Tags: visualization

`ContourPlot` picks a nice set of curves as level curves by default. I'm trying to use the set of curves as mesh curves for corresponding 3D plot, can anyone suggest how I can get those levels extracted out of contour plot?

```
f[x_, y_] := Log[(1 - x)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2];
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 0.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Gray, Thick}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[GrayLevel[1 - .45 #]], Frame -> None]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 0.5}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: You can hunt through for `Tooltip`s

Comment: Hm...tooltips says the curves are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....but using those as Mesh values doesn't give me same curves

Comment: I can't reproduce that - if I change the code you posted, and add in the 5,6,7, and 8, it looks the same as below

Comment: ok looks like I was plotting 2 different functions, thanks for the Tooltip extractor code

Comment: Duplicates: [(31858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31858), [(66487)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66487)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, contours generated by `ContourPlot` have `Tooltip`s with their numerical value as the label.  You can use `Cases` to grab the values programmatically.

```
f[x_, y_] := Log[(1 - x)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2];
plot = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 0.5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> {{Gray, Thick}}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[GrayLevel[1 - .45 #]], Frame -> None]

levels = Union@Cases[plot, Tooltip[_, label_] :> label, Infinity];

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 0.5}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {levels}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, .5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> ((contours = FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}]) &)];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, .5}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {contours}, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

Jason's approach, extracting `Tooltip` labels form `ContourPlot` output, is straightforward and convenient.

For the curious, how *ContourPlot picks a nice set of curves as level curves by default* remains a puzzle.

Speaking of "nice", searching for "nice numbers" in the Documentation Center gives:
[image]

See also: [Google Search: wolfram documentation "nice" numbers.](https://www.google.com/search?ei=wCQyWp7XEpO4jwOS4JLwBw&q=wolfram+documentation++%22nice%22+numbers&oq=wolfram+documentation++%22nice%22+numbers&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3370.8694.0.9542.18.17.0.0.0.0.474.1382.4-3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..15.1.439...0j35i39k1j0i22i30k1.0.9o197T01prI)

[Documentation >> FindDivisions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDivisions.html):
[image]
[image]
[Documentation >> Contours](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Contours.html):
[image]

After a few trials, we find that the function `FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}]&` (where the first two arguments are $z_{min}$ and $z_{max}$ and the last argument is the number of divisions which is fixed at `10`) as the setting for `Contours` gives the same output as the default setting for this option.

Some examples:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}] == 
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  Contours -> (FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}] &)] ==
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  Contours -> (FindDivisions[{#, #2}, 10, Method -> {}] &)]
```

> True

```
rr = RandomReal[5, 2];
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[rr.{x, y}], {5}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}] == 
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[rr.{x, y}], {5}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
   Contours -> (FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}] &)]
```

> True

So for OP's example, we can extract the default contour levels using this function as follows:

```
f[x_, y_] := Log[(1 - x)^2 + 100 (y - x^2)^2];
cp1 = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, .5}, {y, -2, 2}];
levels = Cases[cp1, Tooltip[_, t_]:>t, Infinity];

cp2 = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, .5}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> ((contours = FindDivisions[{#, #2}, #3, Method -> {}]) &)];

cp1 === cp2
```

> True

```
levels == Reverse@contours
```

> True